# How to hide onclick action?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

how to edit the code, to function OnClick worked automatically?
This is code:

```
<form name="statusUpdate" action="" method="">
        <textarea style="width:0; height: 0;" name="status" id="status" readonly>VARIABLE 1  http://bit.ly/VxwZWv </textarea>
        <br />
        <input type="button" onclick="updateStatusViaJavascriptAPICalling(); return false;" value="KLIKNIJ, ABY ROZPOCZAC" />
    </form>
```

and function:

```
            function updateStatusViaJavascriptAPICalling(){
            var status  =   document.getElementById('status').value;
                FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: status }, function(response) {
                    if (!response || response.error) {
                         alert('Error occured');
                    } else {
                         alert('Ok. Teraz w menu wybierz opcje GENERUJ ');
                    }
               });
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: You don't want the user to be able to see that there is a function being called for that button?

Comment: Apologies, but I assume english is not your first language? Are you looking for how to edit the code you've displayed (as in, where to change the value for your result) ? Or are you looking for how to modify the `updateStatusViaJavascriptAPICalling();` call which you didn't provide the code to?

Comment: yes. i want to button and form with variable was hidden

Comment: Do you want to access the textarea periodically as if the user clicked after every keystroke ?

Answer (score 0):

Add the onload attribute to the HTML Body tag:

```
<body onload="updateStatusViaJavascriptAPICalling();">
```

Answer (score 0):

without **jQuery:**

```
<body onload="javascript:function();">
```

**or**

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload=function(){
        };
    </script>
</head>
```

or if using jquery simply put this in your document.ready function and then it will happen on page load instead of on button click.

If you are wanting the button to exist and be hidden no one can click it...but you can do this with hidden inputs and then running the function "sometime".